# Using strpos() to match part of an array, PHP

Tags: php, strpos

I need some help with strpos().

Need to build a way to match any URL that contains `/apple-touch` but also need to keep specifics matching, such as `"/favicon.gif"` etc

At the moment, the matches are listed out individually as part of an array:

```
<?php 

$errorurl = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$blacklist = array("/favicon.gif", "/favicon.png", "/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png", "/apple-touch-icon.png", "/apple-touch-icon-72x72-precomposed.png", "/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png", "/apple-touch-icon-114x114-precomposed.png", "/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png", "/apple-touch-icon-57x57-precomposed.png", "/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png", "/crossdomain.xml");

 if (in_array($errorurl, $blacklist)) { // do nothing }
    else { // send an email about error }

?>
```

Any ideas?

Many thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a regex, you could also remove all occurrences of your blacklist items with [`str_replace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) and compare the new string to the old one:

```
if ( str_replace($blacklist, '', $errorurl) !== $errorurl )
{
  // do nothing
}
else
{
  // send an email about error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regex for this, and you want a single regex string that will capture all the values in your existing blacklist plus match any `apple-touch` string, then something like this would do it.

```
if(preg_match('/^\/(favicon|crossdomain|apple-touch.*)\.(gif|png|xml)$/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) {
    //matched the blacklist!
}
```

To be honest, though, that's far more complex than you need.

I'd say you'd be better off keeping the specific values like `favicon.gif` etc in the blacklist array you already have; it'd make it a lot easier when you come to adding more items to the list.

I'd only consider using regex for the `apple-touch` values, since you want to block any variant of them. But even with that, it would likely be simpler if you used `strpos()`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. How to use strpos() then?

Comment: in fact, I meant `substr()` :)  -- something like `if(substr($uri,0,11)=='apple-touch') {....}`